# SWIG python MacOS issue

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm using MacOS on M1 Pro Macbook and I want to build a minimalistic-example SWIG binding to python.

I have a C++ file:

```
// mymodule.cpp
int square(int x){
    return x*x;
}
```

interface file

```
//mymodule.i
%module mymodule

%{
extern int square(int x);
%}
extern int square(int x);
```

Then I call:

```
swig -c++ -python -o mymodule_wrap.cpp mymodule.i
gcc -c mymodule.cpp mymodule_wrap.cpp -I/Users/XXX/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -fPIC
gcc -shared mymodule.o mymodule_wrap.o -o _mymodule.so
```

and the third line gives me:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What should I change to make it work?